# SearchPattern for Directory.GetDirectories in C#

Tags: c#

Desired search description:

```
Any string that contains either v2 or v3 (case insensitive)
```

I am trying to find subdirectory paths using Directory.GetDirectories(path, searchPattern), and I was going to supply the regex pattern for searchPattern argument, but apparently, searchPattern can't be regex expression.

Are there any other good ways to filter file names that contain v2 or v3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Directory.GetDirectories` doesn't support regex, so you can't use that.

I would use this instead:

```
foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(baseDir, "*v2*")
                      .Concat(Directory.GetDirectories(baseDir, "*v3*"))
        )
{
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be slightly more efficient to call `Directory.GetDirectories(baseDir).Where(d => Regex.IsMatch(d, "v[23]"))` so you're not enumerating the directory contents twice?

Comment: Depends on the number of directories. If it are thousands and just two directories to retrieve, this is just as efficient.

Comment: Would your answer filter both upper case and lower case? It seems that it will only filter lowercases

Comment: Windows doesn't have casing when it comes to file names. So no uppercase/lowercase checks necessary. @djskj189

Comment: @DanWilson If you have many directories then it would be better to also compile the regex once, so that it doesn't get interpreted again for every directory.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use a regex and avoid scanning the list of directories multiple times (to cut down the amount of necessary IO operations), you can do this:

```
var baseDir = "C:\\YourDirectory\\";
// Replace with your own Regex.
var dirNames = new Regex("v2|v3", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var dirsFiltered =
    Directory.EnumerateDirectories(baseDir).Where(dir => dirNames.IsMatch(dir)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getdirectories?view=netframework-4.7.2

> searchPattern String
>  The search string to match against the names
>   of directories. This parameter can contain a combination of valid
>   literal path and wildcard (* and ?) characters, but it doesn't support
>   regular expressions.

One filter:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"d:\sources\");
DirectoryInfo[] dirs = di.GetDirectories("*my filter*");
```

Multiple filters:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"d:\sources\");
DirectoryInfo[] dirs = di.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
  .Where(q => q.Name.Equals("name1", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
              q.Name.Equals("name2", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```